# How to count all data item array in laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

How to count all data item array in laravel, please help me!. Thank you so much!

[image]

**Output**: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[reduce()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-reduce)

> The `reduce` method reduces the collection to a single value, passing
> the result of each iteration into the subsequent iteration:

```php
$count = collect([
    (object)["views_back" => 3],
    (object)["views_back" => 5]
])->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    return $carry + $item->views_back;
});

var_export($count); // 8
```

##### Addendum

Alternatively, using native/vanilla PHP:

```php
$count = array_sum(array_column([
    (object)["views_back" => 3],
    (object)["views_back" => 5]
], "views_back"));

var_export($count); // 8
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. Because I new learn laravel so i don't know reduce, hihi

Answer (score 0):

When working with arrays in Laravel, it can be helpful to convert them to a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) which provides some helper methods for arrays.

If all you want is the number of elements in the array use [`count`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-count).

If you want the sum of the `views_back` elements, use [`reduce`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-reduce%60).

```
$array = [
    [
        'views_back' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'views_back' => 5,
    ]
];

$count = collect($array)->count();

$sum = collect($array)->reduce(function ($carry, $element) {
    return $carry + $element['views_back'];
});

dd($count, $sum);
```

In the above `$count` is `2` and `$sum` is `8`.

If your original data is `json` (as you've used a `json` tag), you will need to convet the data to an array first:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel collection method `sum()` method to write smaller code and make it easier to read.

```php
$data = [
    (object)["views_back" => 3],
    (object)["views_back" => 5]
];

collect($data)->sum('views_back');
```

Converting array to collection can be CPU costly depending on the size of the input array. In that case @steven7mwesigwa vanilla PHP answer would be the best solution.